# Populating Versioning and ObjectId in BaseEntity using Spring and Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

This question have been asked in various forms but none of them seems to answer what I am looking for.

I have been following the example [using-spring-data-to-access-mongodb](http://city81.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/using-spring-data-to-access-mongodb.html). I need to know how to populate the fields in `BaseEntity` when the `Customer` Entity is new? The example does not show how is it populating because I see them `NULL` in my object and these fields don't get persisted when the object is saved.

The other question is, how would the `BaseEntity` get populated when `Customer` object is retrieved from mongodb?

Following links were not helpful

[versioning-of-sets-of-documents-in-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283738/versioning-of-sets-of-documents-in-mongodb)

[java-mongodb-object-versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104969/java-mongodb-object-versioning)

Comment: Populating Person object that extends BaseEntity or Customer object that extends BaseEntity. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Well, I was referring to your title.

Comment: Do you want to suggest a better title?

Comment: I don't know what versioing mean, or did you mean versioning?

Comment: Well thats fixed now. Even though there was a typo I am sure its obvious what is that I am asking :)